# Receive data from JSON AngularJS with 2 keys

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, model-view-controller

I can't read data from my JSON that I receive from a called php and my Controller it's like this:

```
    app.controller('equipoCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$http', function($scope,$routeParams,$http){
    $('.mainApp').removeClass('fluid-container').addClass('container');

    $scope.setActive("mClasificacion");
    var idEquipo = $routeParams.idEquipo;
    $scope.actualizado = false;
    $scope.alumno = {};
    $scope.myposition={};
    $scope.posicionSeleccionada="2";
    $scope.posicionSeleccionada2="1";

    $http.get('php/servicios/equipos.getEquipo.php?c='+ idEquipo)
    .success(function(data){

        if (data.err !== undefined) {
            window.location  = "#/equipos";
            return;
        }
        $scope.alumno = data;

    });


    $http.get('php/servicios/alumnos.posiciones.php')
    .success(function(data){

        $scope.myposition=data;
    });




}]);
```

The result of my array called `myposition` looks like:

```
[ { "idPosicion": "2", "posicion": "Delantero" }, { "idPosicion": "1", "posicion": "Portero" } ]
```

Finally my HTML code:

```
            <div class="col-md-6">
           Posicion Jugador 1:{{posicionSeleccionada}} 
           <select ng-model="posicionSeleccionada" class="form-control" >
              <option ng-repeat="(key,value) in myposition" value=""></option>
           </select>
        </div>
```

Somebody can help me, how can retrieve the values?

Thanks, Luiggi

Comment: You are using object syntax when you need to use array syntax

Comment: OMG!!!!!! can you tell me some example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using object syntax when you need to use array syntax

```
<option ng-repeat="pos in myposition" value="{{pos.idPosicion}}">{{pos.posicion}}</option>
```

Also suggest looking into using [`ng-options`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)

Comment: Study the `ng-repeat` documents... examples show how to do this